# Too many nestings in IF formula. Could I use another formula to achieve what I want?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Don't know if I'm in the right place here. I'm searching for a sollution to my problem of having too many nestings in my IF formula.
I need this to work:

IF(M9="Jan";Participation!FG14, IF(M9="Feb";Participation!FG26, IF(M9="Mar";Participation!FG38, IF(M9="Apr";Participation!FG50, IF(M9="May";Participation!FG62, IF(M9="Jun";Participation!FG74, IF(M9="Jul";Participation!FG86, IF(M9="Aug";Participation!FG98, IF(M9="Sep";Participation!FG110, IF(M9="Oct";Participation!FG122, IF(M9="Nov";Participation!FG134, IF(M9="Dec";Participation!FG146))))))))))))

In M9 I have a drop down list with the months. And depending on the month chosen I want to collect results from another sheet called Participation in the same work book.

Please. Can anyone give me any tips here?

Frank

Comment: What error you are getting while implementing the  IF ?

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want:

```
=INDEX(Participation!FG:FG;(MONTH("1 " & M9 & " 2018")-1)*12+14)
```

Comment: Wow! That totally worked! Except for the months May, October and December. Can't think of why though. But thanks a bunch!

Comment: Check to ensure the there are no extra spaces or other unprintable characters in the drop down for those months.

Comment: Nope. Can't find anything wrong there.

Comment: And they are `May`,`Oct` and `Dec`?

Comment: When you say they do not work, does it return an error or the wrong value?

Comment: It returns a bunch of ######'s

Comment: Did you try to resize the cell to allow more characters?

Comment: Yep. Sorry. I was a bit inacurate in my last comment. It does not return #####. It returns #VALUE!

Comment: I actually tried something myself and that seemed to do the trick, although I can't understand why. I changed the abbreviations for the months in the drop down list, from the english may, oct, and dec, to the Norwegian mai, okt and des.  That solved the problem. But why. I have and English Excel version and the reference sheet also is in English. All the formulas are in English. So how and why it was suddenly required to write these abbreviations in Norwegian is strange.